# Knapsack Solution in Scala With Memoization

Tags: scala, scalaz

Hi I am trying to implement Knapsack solution in Scala with Memoization. Here is the code without memoization

```
// knapsack = maxWeight: Int, weights: List[Int], values: List[Int]
val knapsack: ((Int, List[Int], List[Int]) => Int) = Memo {
     case (0, _, _) | (_, Nil, _) | (_, _, Nil) => 0
     case (weight, headWt :: tailWts, _ :: tailVals) if headWt > weight => 
                                       knapsack(weight, tailWts, tailVals)
     case (weight, headWt :: tailWts, headVal :: tailVals) => math.max(
                                       headVal+knapsack(weight-headWt, tailWts, tailVals),
                                       knapsack(weight-headWt, tailWts, tailVals))  
}

println(knapsack(50, weights.sortBy(-_), values.sortBy(-_)))
```

Here is the definition of Memo :

```
case class Memo[A,B](f: A=>B) extends mutable.HashMap[A,B]{
     override def apply(a: A):B = {
          getOrElseUpdate(a, f(a))
     }
}
```

However, I am getting a compile time error :

```
  Type mismatch, expected: List[Int], actual: List[Any]
```

If I remove Memo it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on which line you get your error

> Type mismatch, expected: List[Int], actual: List[Any]

If I change type of `knapsack` to `(((Int, List[Int], List[Int])) => Int)` i.e. `Function1` from a tuple `(Int, List[Int], List[Int])` to `Int`, your code with `Memo` compiles for me without any errors.

```
// knapsack = maxWeight: Int, weights: List[Int], values: List[Int]
val knapsack: (((Int, List[Int], List[Int])) => Int) = Memo {
  case (0, _, _) | (_, Nil, _) | (_, _, Nil) => 0
  case (weight, headWt :: tailWts, _ :: tailVals) if headWt > weight =>
    knapsack(weight, tailWts, tailVals)
  case (weight, headWt :: tailWts, headVal :: tailVals) => math.max(
    headVal + knapsack(weight - headWt, tailWts, tailVals),
    knapsack(weight - headWt, tailWts, tailVals))
}

val weights: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30)
val values: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
println(knapsack(50, weights.sortBy(-_), values.sortBy(-_)))
```

produces expected

> 7

Comment: Thanks a lot SergGr for your help. Had no clue why its happening. Its such a difficult thing to get it from the compiler error message.